# Issue mapping over array with .map()

Tags: reactjs, array.prototype.map

I have a react component which maps over an array of movies in the render function, and logging out the image of each one. I'm having trouble mapping out each image itself to an `<img />` tag. It currently appears that all of the images are being spit out into the one `<img />` tag, so how can I loop through the images and insert each one into its own image tag?

```
render () {
const movies = this.state.movies.map((movie, i) => {
  console.log("Image url: ", movie.images.boxArt)
})


return (
  <div className='welcome'>
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='movies'>
        { this.state.loading &&
          <Loader size='10' />
        }

        { !this.state.loading &&
          <div className='movie'>
            <img src={ movies } /> <===SHOULD END UP BEING A ROW OF MOVIE POSTERS
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each array element render an image and specify the src. Like this:

```
const movies = this.state.movies.map((movie, i) => <img key={i} src={ movie } />)

<div className='movie'>
    { movies }
</div>
```